# Inserting multidimensional Array into existing SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a large xml file that I am collecting specific information from using XML READER. Once I have all the information stored in the array $content It is then inserted into another array $preOwnedData. making it a multidimensional array.

I am now attempting to Insert the array data into an already existing SQL database using PHP however I am currently getting nowhere! I know the standard way of inserting with MYSQLI.

I'm assuming that with arrays you have to do some kind of looping to go through the array.

The database is already set up and I basically need to insert into it the strings that are in the arrays EXAMPLE:

INSERT INTO $table (id) VALUES (DocumentID) and so on for all the values I require.

**THIS IS PART OF THE var_dump of the  ARRAY**

```
array (size=69)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'DocumentID' => string '898052' (length=6)
      'ChargeAmount' => string '31500' (length=5)
      'URI' => string 'http://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/80/52/898052_0_040820101331_4.jpg' (length=68)
      'MakeString' => string 'Cranchi' (length=7)
      'ModelYear' => string '2001' (length=4)
      'Model' => string 'Perla 25' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'DocumentID' => string '898052' (length=6)
      'ChargeAmount' => string '31500' (length=5)
      'URI' => string 'http://imt.boatwizard.com/images/1/80/52/898052_0_040820101331_4.jpg' (length=68)
      'MakeString' => string 'VOLVO' (length=5)
      'ModelYear' => string '2001' (length=4)
      'Model' => string '4.3 L' (length=5)
```

**PHP CODE CORRECTED THIS CODE IS NOW WORKING**

```
$url="https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/38acaac6-c5c6-4aa6-a40c-41fbc1296515/boats?status=on";
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($url);

$PreOwnedData = array();

while($xml->read()){
    //id
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'DocumentID'){
        $content = array();
        $xml->read();
        $content['DocumentID'] = $xml->value;
    }
    //price
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'ChargeAmount'){
        $xml->read();
        $content['ChargeAmount'] = $xml->value;
    }

    //img
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'URI'){
        $xml->read();
        $content['URI'] = $xml->value;
    }

    //make
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'MakeString'){
        $xml->read();
        $content['MakeString'] = $xml->value;
    }
    //year
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'ModelYear'){
        $xml->read();
        $content['ModelYear'] = $xml->value;
    }
    //model
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'Model'){
        $xml->read();
        $content['Model'] = $xml->value;
        $PreOwnedData[] = $content;
    }

}

//Paramaters for SQL connections  LOCAL
    $hostname="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="test";
    $table="preowned";

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

//Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(count($PreOwnedData) > 0){
        foreach($PreOwnedData as $content){
            $id = $content['DocumentID'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (id) VALUES ('$id')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So - where is `mysqli_query`? You said you know the standard way of inserting with MYSQLI. What's the problem then?

Comment: Sorry, Last bit of code didn't copy over. Basically nothing is getting sent to the DB.  I'm guessing the way you send array information to a DB is different?

Comment: So, you declared `insertoDB` function. Where do you call it?

Comment: Thanks for the point out that I was not calling the function! @u_mulder

Comment: Resolved the issue! Thanks to Adelphia for spotting the backwards variable.
Removing the function solved the issue. I will update the question with the correct code. THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're not calling your function that actually does the inserting. Call it.
2. In your function, `$table` is not defined. Define it.
3. also, this is backwards.. `$content['DocumentID'] = $id;`. Swap it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks the heads up! simple error should have noticed that!